# How to know if Managed Package available in app exchange is Certified from Salesforce or not

Tags: managed-package, cpulimit

We are considering installing the managed package in our org.
We know that if Package is certified then different limits are given by Salesforce to the Package outside our ORG CPU limit.

Is there any way We can verify if package is SFDC certified or not.

*From Salesforce Documentation: Namespaces in packages that are not certified don’t have their own separate governor limits. The resources they use continue to count against the same governor limits used by your org's custom code.*

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the package is available publicly on the salesforce appexchange that means its certified by the salesforce and has successfully passed the salesforce security review process .

If the package is available as a private listing then salesforce puts a security warning there saying the package has not gone through the security process .

Also you can review in your org all the packages installed and it will clearly show you ones not passed in the ***Appexchange Ready*** column.

[image]

Also you can restrict installation of non certified packages using Apex Settings.Keep the "Deploy Metadata From Non-Certified Versions in apex" unchecked.This will auto restrict you from deploying packages that are not certified .

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry I forgot to update it earlier,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is anyway to know but the vendor of the package should be able to confirm. It doesn't appear to be visible on the installed packages page nor on the appexchange listing page.